# Why does $A_\text{TM} \le_m \text{HALTING} \le_m \text{HALTING}^\varepsilon$?

Tags: turing-machines, reductions, undecidability, halting-problem

I have a book that proves the halting problem with this simple statement:

$$
A_\text{TM} \le_m  \text{HALTING} \le_m \text{HALTING}^\varepsilon
$$

It states that halting problem reduces to the language consisting of $\langle M, \omega \rangle$ for which a Turing machine $M$ accepts $\omega$ is undecidable.

What does this mean? What does the notation $\le_m$ indicate?

Comment: Is $\text{HALTING}^\varepsilon$ is the language of all encodings of TMs that stop on the empty tape? $\le_m$ denotes a many-one reduction.

Comment: Thanks! What's a many-one reduction?

Comment: A many-one reduction from $L$ to $L'$ (given an alphabet $\Sigma$) is a (computable) function $f: \Sigma^* \to \Sigma^*$ such that for every $w \in \Sigma^*$, $w \in L$ if and only if $f(w) \in L'$.  The "many-one" means that we allow $f(w) = f(w')$ (it's not injective).  In your settings, it basically means that you can transform an input to $A_{TM}$ to HALTING such that the first accepts the input iff HALTING accepts the transformed input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol $\leq_m$ means [many-one reducible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-one_reduction), contrast to reductions such as turing reducible (denoted by $\leq_T$) and one-one reducible (denoted $\leq_1$).

A many-one reduction from $L$ to $L′$ (given an alphabet $\Sigma$) is a (computable) function $f:\Sigma^* \to \Sigma^*$ such that for every $w \in \Sigma^*$, we have that $w \in L$ if and only if $f(w) \in L′$.  The "many-one" means that we allow $f(w) = f(w′)$ (it does not have to be injective).  In your setting, it basically means that you can transform an input to $A_{TM}$ to $HALTING$ such that $A_{TM}$ accepts an input $w$ if and only if $HALTING$ accepts the transformed input $f(w)$.